# How to export Collections/Request from HTTPie?

Tags: httpie

I've been using HTTPie on Mac OS and I've been enjoying it. The version I'm currently using is: 2024.1.2 (2024.1.2)

I can import to HTTPie smoothly. But how do I export from HTTPie collections or requests?
Another possibility, perhaps, would be to know where the requests are stored locally.

Comment: I just installed the latest version `2024.1.2` today and I find that this feature is not available at the moment. You may track this open GitHub issue: https://github.com/httpie/desktop/issues/22